# Pycharm Django cannot close development runserver with ctrl + c or ctrl + break

Tags: python, django, pycharm

For some reasons I cannot use ctrl + c or ctrl + break (my laptop doesn't have break) to close the django development server in pycharm?

But I can use ctrl + c when I want to exit out of terminal from python? So it seems to me that this problem is django specific perhaps?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to close it?

Comment: Are you using pycharm terminal to run your django project or Pycharm's Run manage.py task in tools that are for django projects?

Comment: @Mojtaba I am using pycharm's terminal by typing python manage.py runserver

Comment: @NickODell as it force close the session? Yeah It will close the entire terminal

Comment: @CountDOOKU No, the question I'm asking here, that I'm asking for clarification about "cannot use ctrl + c or ctrl + break to to close the django development server." What happens when you attempt this? Does nothing happen? Is there an error?

Comment: @NickODell I see my apologies, yes nothing happens (and the terminal is in focus ie I clicked on it before ctrl + c)